# Loop through elements in a variable

Tags: jquery, loops

How would loop through HTML stored in a variable for 'ul' tags? This is what I have so far but the alert() don't even trigger, Im a bit lost...

```
var data = 'HTML';
$('ul', data).each(function(i,v) {
    var theTag = v.tagName;
    var theElement = $(v);
    var theValue = theElement.html();
    alert(theTag+'\n'+theElement+'\n'+theValue);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to use the "selector, context" form of the [`$()` call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

> **jQuery( selector [, context] )**
>   **selector** A string containing a selector expression
>   **context** A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

A string of HTML doesn't match any of the things that `context` is supposed to be so jQuery doesn't know what to do with your arguments and makes the wrong guess.

You probably want to do it like this:

```
$(data).filter('ul').each(function(i,v) {
    //...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gxGB8/

Or, if you don['t know at what level the `<ul>` elements will be, wrap the HTML in a `<div>` and use](http://api.jquery.com/find/) `find` instead of [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('<div>' + data + '</div>').find('ul').each(function(i, v) {
    //...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tM4ua/

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` returns the value of a form input.
It doesn't work on arbitrary elements.

You want `.text()` or `.html()`.

**EDIT**: To find elements in an HTML string, you should write `$(html).find('ul')`

Comment: Thanks but it still dont work. The alert doesn't even trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the data context scope from you ul selector

Comment: If I did that it would loop through the document and not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    // Gets underlying element object
    var theElement = $(this).get(0);

    var theTag = theElement.tagName;

    // Can also use .text() if you want just the textual content
    var theValue = $(this).html();

    // theElement can't be printed, it's an object
    alert(theTag+'\n'+theValue);
});
```

I am presuming here that you want the contents of a number of `<ul>` tags, rather than the `<li>` parts of a single list.

Comment: Btw, if it doesn't get to the alert, open out Firebug or similar - you probably have a JS error.

Comment: I am trying to loop through the elements from a variable not the document itself, is this possible? I have no errors in Firebug console, seems I cant find elements from a variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/QsVwb/)

It could help!