# HTML table in a Var: sum rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have html table in a var and need to sum each row and put total in the last cell, and put the result back to the var (I need it for further programming for SharePoint). The table has fixed rows and TDs.  JS or Jquery is fine. any Ideas. thank you

here is the var:

```
var A1='<table Id="AEid" width="85%" border="3"><tbody>
<tr><th><b>AM1</b></th><th><b>AM2</b></th><th><b>Total</b></th>
</tr><tr><td rowspan="1">​</td><td rowspan="1">​</td><td rowspan="1">​</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="1">​</td><td rowspan="1">​</td><td rowspan="1">​</td></tr></tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. See SO help pages for info on asking questions here.

Comment: There are many examples of how to loop through the var. See this link. But I need to total and put in the cell then put back in the var. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868368/loop-through-elements-in-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create jquery object from your var without attaching to the DOM and manipulate it to heart's content.

```
var newText ='<table><tbody><tr><td>​1</td><td>​2</td><td>​</td></tr><tr><td>​1</td><td>​2</td><td>​</td></tr></tbody></table>';
$newDiv = $(newText);
```

You can refer to the jsfiddle I made. Not the best answer, but will do what you need http://jsfiddle.net/j5pKx/4/. Hope that helps

Comment: It seems we are there, but I need to write it back with totals to my var, because your suggestions would wipe my list. so  I have tried: A1 =  $('table').html($newDiv);
but it did not work!

Comment: The answer to my last comments is this (put it to another var): A2 =($newDiv).html();