# Use each function from jQuery from a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a variable like this:

```
myVar = "<li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li>"
```

I want to loop into this variable to find the `<li>...</li>` parts.

I think the use of `.each` function is the best.

---

It solves my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868497/3992895

Comment: please provide full explanation. Code shown doesn't make a lot of sense. I think you want  `$(myVar).each` but question not clear at all

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you actually want to achieve here, But check this will give you an idea and manipulate it as you want

```
myVar = "<li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li>";
var elemnt=$.parseHTML(myVar);
$(elemnt).each( function(){
  alert(this.outerHTML);
});
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/54rm7f8a/5/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/44nor3zz/)

```
var myVar = "<li>..1.</li><li>..2.</li><li>...3</li>",
    arr = myVar.split('</li>');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    alert(arr[i].replace('<li>', ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/0fmhjwrs/

```
var myVar = "<li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>";

$myVar = $(myVar);

$myVar.each(function() 
{
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
myVar = "<li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li>"

$(myVar).each(function(){
        alert(this);
});
```

Comment: Your code do not search for <li>...</li> but for all the variable content.

Comment: what do you ment with serach? select only one <li>? or search the string "<li>..</li>" ..